# JSoup Elements in ArrayList as Strings are not the same as a String?

Tags: java, arraylist, jsoup

So I was working with JSoup encountering the problem that I wasn't able to compare a String and the text of an selected Element (by JSoup) with each other. The condition is never returning a `true`. Can anyone please help me because I don't now what could be wrong.

My Code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> ElementsToArrList(Elements e) {
    ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (i = 0; i < e.size(); i++) {
        arrList.add(e.get(i).text());
    }
    return arrList;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.fussballdaten.de/bundesliga/").get();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Testingproj.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    e = doc.select("div#rt_zu_Hause > table > tbody > tr > td.Verein > a[href]");

    ArrayList = ElementsToArrList(e);
    ArrayListx.add(s);

    //first Attempt

    for (i = 0; i < ArrayList.size(); i++) {
        if (ArrayList.get(i).equals(ArrayListx.get(0))) {
            System.out.println("Found! -> " + i);
        } else {
            System.out.println(ArrayList.get(i) + " isn't the same as: " + ArrayListx.get(0));
        }
    }

    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    //second Attempt

    for (i = 0; i < ArrayList.size(); i++) {
        if (ArrayList.get(i).equals(s)) {
            System.out.println("Found! -> " + i);
        } else {
            System.out.println(ArrayList.get(i) + " isn't the same as: " + s);
        }
    }

}
```

---

**Output is this:**

*FC Bayern München isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*Borussia Dortmund isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*VfL Wolfsburg isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*FC Schalke 04 isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*Hertha BSC isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*Borussia Mönchengladbach isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*Bayer Leverkusen isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*1. FC Köln isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*1. FSV Mainz 05 isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*Eintracht Frankfurt isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*SV Darmstadt 98 isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*VfB Stuttgart isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

***Hamburger SV isn't the same as: Hamburger SV***

*FC Ingolstadt 04 isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*FC Augsburg isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*1899 Hoffenheim isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*Hannover 96 isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*SV Werder Bremen isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

---

*FC Bayern München isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*Borussia Dortmund isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*VfL Wolfsburg isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*FC Schalke 04 isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*Hertha BSC isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*Borussia Mönchengladbach isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*Bayer Leverkusen isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*1. FC Köln isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*1. FSV Mainz 05 isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*Eintracht Frankfurt isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*SV Darmstadt 98 isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*VfB Stuttgart isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

***Hamburger SV isn't the same as: Hamburger SV***

*FC Ingolstadt 04 isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*FC Augsburg isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*1899 Hoffenheim isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*Hannover 96 isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

*SV Werder Bremen isn't the same as: Hamburger SV*

Pay special attention to the bold outprints: They show that the String "Hamburger SV" is actually held in the ArrayList but it doesn't equals for some reason.

I only used "static" because it wasn't possible otherwise. Shouldn't be a source for the error though I tried the similar code in another project without static variables.

I would like to know how i can fix it so that i get a `true` return from my

```
if(ArrayList.get(i).equals(ArrayListx.get(0))){
```

*or* my

```
 if(ArrayList.get(i).equals(s)){
```

Thanks already.

Comment: Try trimming whitespace: arrList.add(e.get(i).text().trim());

Comment: what is variable `s`?

Comment: @wero that's a string, sorry my fault there :)

Comment: @AlanHay not working with .trim()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see `it` (see below) is [Non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

Change

`arrList.add(e.get(i).text());`

to

`arrList.add(e.get(i).text().replace("\u00a0", " "));`

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks!!! Honestly i thought this got interpreted right by Netbeans but it was only the output as it seems.. thanks man, this was grinding my gears! :)